# How do I combine two rows into one single row by overriding NULL values using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two rows like this:

```
id    title            format    region    discs    user_id    origin_id
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     12 Monkeys       DVD       NULL      NULL     NULL       NULL
2     Twelve Monkeys   NULL      NULL      1        2          1
```

I want to do a `SELECT` call that always returns the data when a `user_id` is not `NULL`. Here's what the result I am looking for should be:

```
id    title            format    region    discs    user_id   origin_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2     Twelve Monkeys   DVD       NULL      1        2         1
```

As you can see, `format` got filled from `id 1` because of `NULL` on `id 2`, but everything else was filled from id 2.

What is the MySQL statement that can do this for me?

Comment: How do you know to combine these two rows?  Does you table only have two rows?

Comment: I just added the `origin_id` column that connects the two. They will come from a `SELECT` off a `user_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your given data, you can use a `left join` and `coalesce()` to prioritize the values:

```
select coalesce(t.id, t2.id) as id,
       coalesce(t.title, t2.title) as title,
       coalesce(t.format, t2.format) as format,
       coalesce(t.region, t2.region) as region,
       coalesce(t.discs, t2.discs) as discs,
       t.user_id
from t left join
     t t2
     on t2.user_id is null
where t.user_id is not null;
```